# How to use mget method with variable?

Tags: windows, ftp

I'd like to download some files with some format(XXX_%date%) by mget comand of ftp on Windows. With regard to XXX_%date%, XXX is a fix name, say 'abc', while %date% is date variable, say 'YYYYMMDD'. How can I set the parameter of mget to download data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is echo the command with variable to a script file, then using the script file as parameter for the ftp command:

reference:
http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/331715-dos-ftp-using-variables.html